# Combining two xml files php

Tags: php, xml, merge

file 1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<urunler>
  <urun>
    <urunkod>2296</urunkod>
    <urunadi><![CDATA[Nuk Kauçuk Emzik No.3 (18+ Ay) -Fun-]]></urunadi>
    <desi>1</desi>
    <stok>113</stok>
    <satis>5.46</satis>
  </urun>
</urunler>
```

---

File 2

```
<urunler>
  <urun id="2296" secenekid="4" grup="YAS;" ozellik="1" fiyat="0" agirlik="0" Stok="0"/>
  <urun id="2296" secenekid="5" grup="YAS;" ozellik="2" fiyat="0" agirlik="0" Stok="0"/>
</urunler>
```

---

I want to get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<urunler>
  <urun>
    <urunkod>2296</urunkod>
    <urunadi><![CDATA[Nuk Kauçuk Emzik No.3 (18+ Ay) -Fun-]]></urunadi>
    <desi>1</desi>
    <stok>113</stok>
    <satis>5.46</satis>
    <options>
      <option>
        <urunid>2296</urunid>
        <grup>YAS</grup>
        <ozellik>1</ozellik>
        <stok>0</stok>
      </option>
      <option>
        <urunid>2296</urunid>
        <grup>YAS</grup>
        <ozellik>2</ozellik>
        <stok>0</stok>
      </option>
    </options>
  </urun>
</urunler>
```

Comment: I do not know much about the subject, I have not tried it before, I am waiting for your help

Comment: This is no place to just solve your problems, please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you need a help with logic of sorting algorithm for this case, I can try to help you.

At first you need to assign xml content to some php variable from your first xml file:

```
$file_1 = simplexml_load_file("file_1.xml") or die("Error: 
Cannot create object";
```

Now you have to parse second xml file to get all attributes for each id and make a collecton of your options as helper array:

```
$options = array();

$file_2 = simplexml_load_file("file_2.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
foreach ($file_2->urunler->urun as $urun_2) {
   $id = $urun_2('id');
   $grup = $urun_2('grup'); // you may apply some filter here
   $ozellik = $urun_2('ozellik');
   $stok = $urun_2('stok');

   array_push($options, array(
      'id' => $id,
      'grup' => $grup,
      'ozellik' => $ozellik,
      'stok' => $stok
   );
}
```

Now you can add child nodes to your first xml file through multiple foreach loop with the id comparision:

```
foreach ($file_1->urunler->urun as $urun_1) { // for each node from file 1
   foreach ($options as $option) { // for each option from your helper collection
      if ($urun_1->urunkod == $option['id']) { // if id from some of your option is equal to the current node from the file 1
         if ($urun_1->options == null) { // add options node if not exist
            $urun_1->addChild("options");
         }

         $option = $urun_1->options->addChild("option");

         $option->addChild("urunid");
         $option->addChild("grup");
         $option->addChild("ozellik");
         $option->addChild("stok");

         $option->urunid = $option['id'];
         $option->grup = $option['grup'];
         $option->ozellik = $option['ozellik'];
         $option->stok = $option['stok'];
      }
   }
}

$file_1->save('file_1_v2.xml');‘
```

May be also helpful for you: how to use simple xml in php https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_xml_simplexml_get.asp